# iPad 6th gen doesn't connect to android hotspot but connects with another iPhone

Tags: ipad, network, wifi, tethering, android

I have iPad 6th generation WiFi-only model. It does not connect to my Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 mobile internet hotspot and other WiFi connections. However it connects to the hotspot of my iPhone SE model.

Interestingly both handsets uses same carriers. Restart, erasing network settings have already been done. How can I connect it to the said mobile's hotspot?

Comment: fwiw, I've seen two different androids not connecting to my iPhone SE.  There have also been questions of windows not connecting to iPhone(iOS 13) and they've been solved. I understand both are not the same case, but one can take hints. What are your iOS btw?

Comment: I am using latest updated version of iOS 13.